# How to solve XY-Grid responsive behaviour challenge in Foundation Sites v6.5.3

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

There's a responsive header I'm trying to execute for a website and I cannot fathom how to achieve it in the new XY-Grid. I've got kind of close, although completely failed with the Orange block at Small breakpoint

I failed to get the Red element to tuck under the orange and blue at Large sizes (but can hack it via negative margins) due to xy-grid clearing rows and not supporting floats.

```
<div class="grid-x align-right">
    <div class="cell small-5 medium-4 large-3" style="background-color:green;">
        GREEN
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-7 medium-8 large-9">
        <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell medium-12 large-7" style="background-color:orange;">
            <!-- Does not yet move above GREEN at small -->
                ORANGE
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-5" style="background-color:blue;">
                BLUE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-12 medium-12 large-9" style="background-color:red;">
        <!--Negative margin set at LARGE breakpoint (not a good solution)-->
        RED
    </div>
</div>
```

I've made an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, flexbox just wasn't designed to do what you're trying to do. I believe this would be a use case for **grid** over *flexbox*.

If you really want to stick with default classes and using Foundation then [this is the best I could get it (codepen)](https://codepen.io/andyusdigital/pen/mgydaK), based on the image you've provided. Your HTML is at the top and mine is at the bottom so we can see a direct comparison of behaviour at breakpoints.

I'm sure someone with some better chops than myself might be able to see a different solution to this, in which case I'd be really interested in seeing it!

```
<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="orange cell small-12 medium-9 medium-order-2 large-4 large-order-2">
    ORANGE
  </div>
  <div class="green cell small-6 medium-3 medium-order-1 large-4 large-order-1">
    <p>GREEN</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blue cell small-6 medium-9 medium-offset-3 medium-order-3 large-4 large-offset-0 large-order-3">
    BLUE
  </div>
  <div class="red cell small-12 medium-12 medium-order-4 large-8 large-order-4 large-offset-4">
    RED
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when more content is added to each div, it pushes down the whole 'row' of content so they all take up 100% height of the space.

This is where grid comes in and if you use it with breakpoints, then you'll be able to shift the elements around the space you have.

[Here's a great guide to using grid.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thank you Andy - I guess you confirmed that the newest Foundation framework and their XY-Grid had limitations. It wasn't just me! I investigated the Grid css parameters and learnt a LOT! I've solved my dilemma, https://codepen.io/mrEdge/pen/LvppbY. Now I just need to figure out how to make it work in IE10+ :(

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help. I also believe that there would be a way to do this with the XY-Grid but I'm yet to have a real play with it and wrap my head around it. If anybody else has some experience with this then I'd love to see how you've solved it!

Comment: Fixed for IE10+ with some additional -ms grid css tags. Would be cumbersome to do if my whole site used Grid (would use a polyfill in that case) but for this it was easy enough.